# seeking work around for compiz's "desktop zoom" for gnome ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, compiz

Is there a method for achieving the compiz feature called "desktop zoom" via either a tiling or zoom enhancement for gnome ubuntu 18.04? This feature lets you shrink full screen to one quadrant of the screen, then lets you zoom in so that the 1/4 screen is now full screen. All text is magnified this way and is good for video explanations. The cursor is restricted to the zoomed tile.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044180/is-there-a-better-way-to-zoom-in/1157436

Answer (score 0):

I've been using that feature for a long time due to my bad eyes. Unfortunately neither Unity or Gnome has been up to par.

After resolving a moustracking bug, it is now perfect in KDE! I use `xbindkeys` to zoom using the `super key + scroll` and it it's perfect. So try Kubuntu 18.04, KDE-neon, OpenSuSE or Arch + KDE.